# AWS CloudFront adding new domain to distribution and setting new certificate

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

So I'm trying to automate the adding of a new domain to an existing CF distribution and I am getting a `Rate exceeded` error message.

I am using `aws/aws-sdk-php`, but I get the same error when I try the same command using `aws-cli`.

This is the code I have so far:

```php
private function addDistributionAliasAndSetNewCertificate(string $distributionId, string $domainName, string $certificateARN): void
{
    $result = $this->cloudFront->getDistributionConfig(['Id' => $distributionId]);

    $eTag = $result['ETag'];
    $distributionConfig = $result['DistributionConfig'];

    // if the domain is already in the distribution return early.
    if (in_array($domainName, $distributionConfig['Aliases']['Items'], true)) {
        StdOut::writeLine("Domain `{$domainName}` already found in distribution `{$distributionId}` config.");
        return;
    }

    $distributionConfig['Aliases']['Items'][] = $domainName;
    $distributionConfig['Aliases']['Quantity'] = count($distributionConfig['Aliases']['Items']);

    $distributionConfig['ViewerCertificate'] = [
        'ACMCertificateArn' => $certificateARN,
        'MinimumProtocolVersion' => 'TLSv1.1_2016',
    ];
    $distributionConfig['Comment'] = 'Updated by `' . getenv('HOST') . '` on `' . date(DATE_ATOM) . '`';

    try {
        $this->cloudFront->updateDistribution([
            'Id' => $distributionId,
            'DistributionConfig' => $distributionConfig,
            'IfMatch' => $eTag,
        ]);
    } catch (CloudFrontException $e) {
        StdOut::writeLine($e->getAwsErrorMessage());
    }
}
```

This goes into the `catch` block with the error message `Rate exceeded`

When I do the same using the cli tools I get this output:
`An error occurred (Throttling) when calling the UpdateDistribution operation (reached max retries: 4): Rate exceeded`

I've waited days between calls and it make 0 difference. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The problem was that I was overriding/removing the `ViewerCertificate.SSLSupportMethod` key.